# A simple pg/plsql loop example

Tags: postgresql, data-migration, plpgsql

We are redesigning table schema in postgres. It used to have a linker table to the two tables `partner` and `advertiser` of the name `partner_advertiser` since we were assuming a many-many relationship between partner and advertiser. A change is made such that an `advertiser` shall have only one `partner`, so `partner` will have a one-may relationship to `advertiser`.

How do I make the change without losing previous information? The linker table data must be used to fill in the mapping of the new schema design.
Here is my initial code:

```
BEGIN

FOR r IN SELECT partnerid, advertiserid from partner_advertiser
    LOOP
    NEXT r;
    UPDATE advertiser SET partnerid = r.partnerid WHERE id = r.advertiserid 
    END LOOP;

END
```

BTW I haven't done any pg/plsql myself. So if there are any basic steps I should make please give me a heads-up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use:

```
UPDATE advertiser a SET partnerid = r.partnerid
FROM partner_advertiser r
WHERE a.id = r.advertiserid
```

Generally, simple relational transformations like these will never need a loop.
If you really need one, though, look at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html

One extra note: any transformation will obviously lose data if advertiserid is not already unique, thus you should first run something like

```
SELECT count(*), advertiserid FROM partner_advertiser
GROUP BY advertiserid HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If any rows get returned by that you will want to fix that manually.

Comment: Note that the update succeeds even if there are multiple tuples in partner_advertiser table for a single advertiser.

Comment: it works. I never thought there is a simple command like that.

Answer (score 6):

This also works. Using a simple `plpgsql` snippet:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTIOn migratePartnerAdvertiser() RETURNS int4 AS '
DECLARE r RECORD;

BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT * from partner_advertiser LOOP
            UPDATE advertiser SET partnerId = r.partnerId WHERE id = r.advertiserId; 
    END LOOP;
return 1;
END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;


SELECT migratePartnerAdvertiser() as output;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
DECLARE id integer;
r record;
BEGIN<BR>
INSERT INTO tabla1(campo1, campo2) VALUES(UPPER(d1),UPPER(d2));<BR>
id = (SELECT LASTVAL());<BR>
FOR r IN SELECT mi_campo FROM tabla2 LOOP<BR>
    INSERT INTO tabla3(campo1, campo2, campo3)<BR>
    VALUES(0, id, r.mi_campo);<BR>
END LOOP;<BR>
END;
```